# Elements created by jQuery do not inherit all CSS properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have looked around but I can not find a question that can solve this in the cleanest fashion. Most responses that delivered circumvent this more arbitrated process by creating a very specialized or direct script. I want to reflect a flexible and organized page/script structure.

Essentially, I want to create a list that grows according to a jQuery script here:

```
window.onload = function()
{

    var feed = document.getElementById("feed");

    //for every number between 100 and 200      
    for (var i = 100; i < 200; i++)
    {
        if ( i % 17 == 0 && i % 2 == 0) //if number evenly divisible by 17 and 2
        {
            var newFeedItem = document.createElement("feedElementBox");
            var feedElementTextNode = document.createTextNode(i);
            newFeedItem.appendChild(feedElementTextNode);
            feed.appendChild(newFeedItem);

        }
    }
    //return feed;
}
```

Here is the HTML web page itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="../js/jsPlay.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    feedElementBox {
        border-left:1px solid; 
        border-right:1px solid;
        border-bottom:1px solid;
        border-top:1px solid;
        height:100px;
        width:100px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
</head>
<h3>feed embedded</h3>

<body>

<div id="feed"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are some screenshots of the rendered web page on chrome:

chrome's display of the css attributes one of the elements:
[image: chrome's display of the css attributes one of the elements]

what chrome says the web page, notice that css appears twice
[image: what chrome says the web page, notice that css appears twice]

the rendered elements^
[image: the rendered elements]

Is there a solution that can allow me to make the elements inherit the CSS properties? As you can see the elements default to the size of the text and this is not what I want. I want a statically allocated space and vertically align these generated elements.

I am new to jQuery and CSS and HTML. Also to note, this web page is displayed in an iframe on another web page.

Comment: Have you considered using Polymer? http://www.polymer-project.org/

Comment: A number is evenly divisible by 17 and 2 if and only if it is divisible by 34, so `i % 34 == 0` would suffice.

Comment: If you're new to jQuery, CSS and HTML, you shouldn't be making up your own elements - you should be probably be using divs for this particular example with a class `feedelementbox` applied to them, and use your CSS to apply those styles to that class. There's no reason why what you're doing shouldn't work if you do that

Comment: @scrowler so could i just change the css block to div.feedElementBox {...} ?

Comment: Yes, then create a div element instead of a feedelementbox element, and add the feedelementbox class to that div

Comment: @scrowler, ok that should work, i just am still new to the syntax. could you point me in the direction of creating my own elements just for giggles?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: add
`display: block`
to the feedElementBox declaration block.

You have declared a CSS rule set where the selector matches any element with tag type feedElementBox.  Since the elements that you are adding to the page are of type feedElementBox, the styles in the feedElementBox declaration block are all applied to those elements.

You have confirmed this by inspecting the elements in the chrome debugger.  In the third image, you can see that the elements match the feedElementBox selector and therefore have the appropriate styles applied.

Your problem is not that the CSS rules are failing to apply, but rather that you have not properly styled the element to get the results that you want.  As @scrowler mentioned, you don't have a valid reason to be using custom elements, and should instead be using div elements.  To apply styles, give applicable elements a feedElementBox class, and change your css selector to be `.feedElementBox` instead of `feedElementBox`.  div elements have the block display property by default.